# Systemd script fail

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I want to run a script at system startup in a Debian 9 box. My script works when run standalone, but fails under systemd.

My script just copies a backup file from a remote server to the local machine:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

/usr/bin/sshpass -p "PASSWORD" /usr/bin/scp -p USER@10.0.0.2:ORIGINPATH/backupserver.zip DESTINATIONPATH/backupserver/
```

Just for privacy I replaced password, user, and paths above.

I wrote the following systemd service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=backup script

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=PATH/backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then I set permissions for the script:

```
chmod 744 PATH/backup.sh
```

And installed the service:

```
chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/backup.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable backup.service
```

When I reboot the script fails:

```
● backup.service - backup script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/backup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-05-13 13:39:54 -03; 47min ago
 Main PID: 591 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Result of journalctl -xe:

```
mai 16 23:34:27 rodrigo-acer systemd[1]: backup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=6/NOTCONFIGURED
mai 16 23:34:27 rodrigo-acer systemd[1]: Failed to start backup script.
mai 16 23:34:27 rodrigo-acer systemd[1]: backup.service: Unit entered failed state.
mai 16 23:34:27 rodrigo-acer systemd[1]: backup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: The systemd journal should have recorded all of its output. Try `journalctl -u backup`

Comment: And remember you don't have to reboot to try running a systemd job. Get it working with `systemctl start backup` first.

Comment: Apart from a couple of SPECIFIERS (find that section in `man systemd.unit`), systemd does *not* perform environment variable substitution in unit files.

Comment: Other things I would do: set PATH explicitly in your script, or use absolute paths for all commands.

Comment: @ZanLynx, I read the OP is indicating that they just replaced that for the question as an anonymization effort ("replaced password, user, and paths above"), and that it's really a legit absolute path in the genuine code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree, but his sshpass commands and such in the script might be failing because of the PATH environment variable settings.

Comment: Ah, right. Missed what you were saying -- that's absolutely a possibility. That said, I'm more inclined to let them actually read the journal (and perhaps learn something themselves) rather than running ahead with guesses at this point.

Comment: @ZanLynx Changed to use full path for sshpass and scp, but still not working. I've run journalctl - u backup and updated the question.

Answer (score 4):

Solved guys. There was 2 problems:

1 - I had to change the service unit file to make the service run only after network was up. The unit section was changed to:

```
 [Unit]
 Description = World server backup
 Wants = network-online.target
 After = network.target network-online.target
```

2 - The root user did not have the remote host added to the known host list, unlike the ordinary user I used to test the script.

Answer (score 2):

Failed with result 'exit-code' you could try this on your last line:

```
# REQUIRED FOR SYSTEMD: 0 means clean no error
exit 0
```

You may also need to add:

```
Type=forking
```

to the systemd entry similar to: https://serverfault.com/questions/751030/systemd-ignores-return-code-while-starting-service

If your service or script does not fork add a & at the end to run it in the background, and exit with 0 fast. Otherwise it will be like a startup that times out and takes forever / seems like frozen service.